# Delete chat message completely

Tags: support, chat

When I delete a message on chat, it just change the content to:

> *(removed)*

Is there a way to delete it completely?

Comment: No need to add "SOLVED" into the question. That's not how things work here. Having it as answer is enough, and you can accept your own answer 48 hours after asking the question

Comment: uh... how do you even delete a chat message to begin with?

Comment: How to delete a chat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug and there is no way to delete it permanently. Same way that posts on the sites are only "soft deleted", so that certain users (OP, 10k rep users, moderators, etc) can still see them, this is also the case with chat messages.

Even after deleting a chat message, any user who is Room Owner of the room where it was posted, and any diamond moderator, can still see the message.

However, such messages will not appear in search results, and not appear for ordinary users in the transcript, so I can't see any problem.

Same with posts on the sites, if you really want a "hard delete" so that nobody can ever see it again, you should contact the SE team via "contact us" link in the footer, and explain why.